# VBO - What can I do at initialization?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I have a VBO interleaved with [x, y, z, textureX, textureY,.....] all pretty much working and displaying. I'm trying to figure out what can be done at initialization and forgotten.

Here is what I'm currently trying at initialization.

EDITED: Fixed unbinding of my buffer and moved some code around.

```
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "vPosition");
        mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_Texture");
        mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glBufferObjects.get(0));
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, interleavedBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, interleavedBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);          

        //////////These are superfluous but I'd like to do them once since they never change///// 
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                INTERLEAVED_VERTEX_TEXTURE_STRIDE, 3 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                INTERLEAVED_VERTEX_TEXTURE_STRIDE, 0);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "uMVPMatrix");

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, glBufferObjects.get(1));
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                drawListBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_SHORT,
                drawListBuffer,
                GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Here is what works. I've messed around a bunch but I can't tell whats required per draw frame because its needed or I'm just doing it wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glBufferObjects.get(0));
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, glBufferObjects.get(1));        

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            INTERLEAVED_VERTEX_TEXTURE_STRIDE, 3 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT);


    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            INTERLEAVED_VERTEX_TEXTURE_STRIDE, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

EDIT: UPDATE - If I remove

```
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, mTextureCoordinateDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            INTERLEAVED_VERTEX_TEXTURE_STRIDE, 3 * BYTES_PER_FLOAT);


    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            INTERLEAVED_VERTEX_TEXTURE_STRIDE, 0);
```

From my draw() it throws a gl_draw_error_checks:418: GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Comment: *"Here is what works"* - And what doesn't *"work"* (and in which way)?

Comment: Removing glVertexAttribPointer or assigning it in initialization and not putting it per draw frame will not display my object. I'm going to go out on a limb and say the required stuff is useProgram + glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, + glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER + the glDrawElements. I kept looking and maybe what I'm looking for ais a Vertex Array Object? I want the draw frame to only call whats barebones needed.

Comment: I've continued to research and it looks like I shouldn't be passing my  handles to glEnableVertexAttribArray, I should be generating them.. maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The calls to glEnableVertexAttribArray and glVertexAttribPointer are needed every frame if you are not using extensions.

However if the extension OES_vertex_array_object is available then you can use Vertex Array objects to store this info with the VBO data. Then you only need to call glBindVertexArray and glDrawArrays every frame.